# How to fill headers and footers using object-oriented approach in MATLAB report generator?

Tags: matlab

I am working with Matlab Report Generator package and its DOM API to create a Word document.

I am using the *object-oriented approach* (described [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/mlreportgen.dom.document.fill.html)), that is to say place a hole in my Word template and have the corresponding fillHoleId method in my Document class.

So far, this approach gives satisfying results, except for headers and footers: despite placing holes in the header/footer of my Word template, they are not filled when generating the document and remain empty.

I suspect that, under the hood, there is a loop under the *fill* method of *Document* class on the holes of this document, and that it does not look for holes in header/footers.

Did anyone encounter the same issue ? How did you resolve it, without breaking too much the object-oriented approach ?

Comment: If the report is about to be **final** and **locked** for further edit I, personally, would create `.pdf` through `-TeX`.

Comment: I completely agree with you. The fact is I have project requirements to output a .docx document using the MATLAB report gen toolbox, otherwise I would have definitely gone for another report generation stack.